# vector - clarification

Tags: calculus

I am reading first chapter in my multivariable calculus textbook, and I have trouble understanding one thing.

Let $e^i \in \mathbb{R}^n, e^i=[0,...,0, 1 ,0,...,0]$ where $1$ is i-th coordinate ( I wasn't able to find the name for this function in English). In my textbook there is a remark that claims that every vector $\vec{x}=[x_1,...,x_n]$ can be also written as $\vec{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ie^i$, I don't understand how this work, I took for example $\vec{x}=[x_1,x_2]$, then the summation and I got something like $x_1[1,0]+x_2[0,1]$ I don't see how that is same as $\vec{x}=[x_1,x_2]$. I seem to be be misunderstanding something.

Comment: $\vec{x}=(x_1,0)+(0,x_2)=x_1(1,0)+x_2(0,1)=x_1 e^1 + x_2 e^2$

Comment: and why is $\vec{x}=[x_1,x_2]=[x_1,0]+[0,x_2]$?

Comment: if $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2)$ and $\vec{b}=(b_1,b_2)$ then $\vec{a}+\vec{b}=(a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2)$ (by definition).

Comment: ah, I get it now, thank you, if you wrote the the first comment as answer I would accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, $\vec{x}=(x_1,0)+(0,x_2)=x_1(1,0)+x_2(0,1)=x_1 e^1 + x_2 e^2$.